# A conjecture about prime test

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> **Conjecture** If $\varphi(m)<\varphi(n)$ for all $m<n$,then $n$ is a prime number.

I tried to find a counterexample when $n=pq$ ($p,q$ are prime), then we have to find a prime between $(p-1)(q-1)$ and $pq$, but I don't know if this is an open problem.

Comment: FYI, if $p$ and $q$ are almost the same value (so $(p-1)(q-1)$ is about $(p-1)^2$ and $pq$ is about $p^2$), then finding a counter-example as you describe is closely related to [Legendre's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture). Thus, I suspect your conjecture is an open problem.

Comment: Wrong argument. Here $p, q$ are primes, a big  difference with Legendre's conjecture. Of course, you can suspect anything. I have not seen this problem before.

Comment: @Graviton: The OP knows that, so the hint is not helpful.

Comment: You will find a counterexample if you find $n$ with no primes between $\phi(n)$ and $n$. By Bertrand postulate there are no even $n$ with this property because then $\phi(n)\le n/2$.  Note that by M. El Bachraoui's result, the counterexample cannot be divisible by $3$ because then $n>3/2\phi(n)$ and there is a prime in this interval ( El Bachraoui, Mohamed (2006), "Primes in the interval $[2n,3n]$", International Journal of Contemporary Mathematical Sciences, 1). The prime number theorem can be applied to show that one can replace $3$ by any prime $p$ and "$n$" by "sufficiently large $n$".

Comment: For $2\le n\le 10^8$ , the conjecture holds. Of course, this primality criterion is only of theoretical interest.

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417511/a-conjecture-about-prime-test